# Mover div fixa junto com scrollbar do navegador horizontalmente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estou com uma complicação sem solução...
Pensei, pensei e não consegui resolver.

```
body{
min-width:900px;
min-height:700px;
}
#topo{
margin-top:0px;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:40px;
background:black;
color:white;
}
barra_esquerda{
margin-top:45px;
position:fixed;
width:40px;
height:300px
background:black;
color:white;
}
```

Nesse exemplo acima acredito que sirva, ao diminuir a dimensão do navegador ficando inferior ao **min-width** e **min-height** irá aparecer o *scrollbar* do navegador, e o site é todo em *absolute*, sendo assim quando eu movimento as barras *scroll* essas divs ficam fixas porque estão fixas, a div **#topo** tudo bem, mas a **#barra_esquerda** gostaria que se movesse também porém deixando ela em *absolute* ao mover o *scroll* na *vertical* ela sobe mas não quero que ela suba, gostaria que essa barra ficasse sempre visível e ao mover o *scrollbar* na *horizontal* do navegador ela andasse junto.

Já tentei deixar a **barra_esquerda** em *absolute* transformando em *fixed* ao mover o *scroll* com javascript, porém *fixed* não se move.

Comment: Cara coloca o CSS inteiro e o HTML também, só com esse pedaço de código não da para ajudar...

Comment: Vc quer que a #barra_esquerda só saia da tela se mover na horizontal?

Comment: Não quero que a div absolute suba ao mover o scrollbar do navegador na vertical, mas quero que ela ande junto com o site ao mover o scrollbar do navegador na horizontal, é isso...

Comment: @Sam sim, isso mesmo...

Answer (score 2):

Cara esse seu CSS não está muito bom, não acredito que seja a melhor forma de fazer isso... De qualquer forma segue um opção, ela basicamente substitui a `position:fixed`, por `position:sticky` dessa forma a `div` da esquerda fica parada apenas no eixo `Y` a 55px do topo, porem ela fica "livre" no eixo `X`

***Para funcionar direito a barra da esquerda não deve ser maior que a altura da janela, tente usar valores em % se for seguir com essa opção***

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```css
  body{
min-width:900px;
min-height:700px;
}
#topo{
margin-top:0px;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:40px;
background:black;
color:white;
z-index: 1;
}
.barra_esquerda{
top:55px;
position:sticky;
width:40px;
height:100px;
background:black;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="topo">topo</div>
<div class="barra_esquerda">esquerda</div>
```

Comment: tá aí a diferença de top & margin-top, valeu brother [y]

Comment: @Jonathan uma das diferenças sim, mas te muito mais coisa rss, depois estude sobre o box model e positions pra entender mais

Answer (score 0):

Troque as propriedades `margin-top` por `top` e utilize `left: 0` para posicionar os elementos corretamente.

Depois use o evento `scroll` do `window` para alternar as propriedades do elemento quando o `.scrollLeft()` for maior ou igual a `0`. O `.scrollLeft()` maior que `0` significa que foi feito um scroll horizontal.

Como a div está a `45px` do topo, ao alterar para position absolute (quando fizer scroll horizontal), é preciso somar essa distância ao scroll da janela, para que a div fique sempre posicionada na distância correta do topo. Ao alterar a div de `fixed` para `absolute`, ela irá acompanhar o scroll horizontal.

Veja como fica:

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
   if($(window).scrollLeft() > 0){
      $("#barra_esquerda").css({
         "position": "absolute",
         "top": $(window).scrollTop()+45+"px"
      });
   }else{
      $("#barra_esquerda").css({
         "position": "fixed",
         "top": "45px"
      });
   }
});
```

```css
body{
min-width:900px;
min-height:700px;
}
#topo{
top:0px;
left: 0;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:40px;
background:black;
color:white;
}
#barra_esquerda{
top:45px;
left: 0;
position:fixed;
width:40px;
height:300px;
background:black;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topo">
   topo
</div>
<div id="barra_esquerda">
   barra_esquerda
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado @Sam, superou minhas expectativas com essa solução rápida! Grato [y]